# Calculate the sum of numbers in column G of MS Excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

When I calculate the sum of numbers in the column G of a Microsoft [Excel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) spreadsheet by using the formula `=SUM(G1,G31)` ,column G32 prints the date (0-Jan-00).
Is there any way in which the sum of numbers in the column G can be calculated?

I am using MS excel 2003 SP3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm. Interesting.

A couple of random ideas (to try on a **copy** of your work book)...

1) Make sure there is no conditional formatting in effect for cell G32

2) Try cutting an adjacent cell that does work onto cell G32, then fix the formula so it calculates for column G.

3) Delete column G, then insert a new column and recreate the data and calculation

4) It is possible the workbook is corrupted;

- Open Excel (without opening you workbook)
- Use **FILE / OPEN**, and navigate to the your workbook. Click Once on he workbook.
- Click on the **Down Arrow** that is on the **OPEN** button, and select **OPEN AND REPAIR**

Comment: You are welcome. Have a fine New Year.

Answer (score 0):

The format of cell G32 must be set to date.

Change it to General. That is, numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the cell's formatting set to date format. Changing it to **General** should fix the problem:

[image]

For future reference there is a much easier way to sum values than writing your own formulas.

- Highlight all of the cells you want to sum
- Click the AutoSum icon in the toolbar that looks like this:

[image]

- The sum should be placed in the cell immediately below the last value in the sum (G32 for you)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
The formatting of all the cells is set to 'General' and not date.
This problem happens only with the column G and not with any other column.
I did try the Autosum icon also .However even that does not work.

Comment: What about the G32 cell?

Comment: The G32 cell is also General.
I am actually calculating the the sum for some data for the whole year.I can make t work for 11 months except for July(represented in column G).

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I used excel, but from what I recall, if you're trying to sum the values in the cells between G1 and G31, you want `=SUM(G1:G31)` (colon, rather than comma)

Answer (score 0):

Chance is that one of the fields in the row you want to calculate is set to date.